# Saving a Django Project in VSCode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, virtual-environment

I am currently setting up a project of Python Django in VSCode, I have created a Virtual Environment and worked on it for a day and after my day was done, I turned off VSCode. And the next morning I do not the Virtual Env in my root! Is this a common thing or I just need to create Virtual Env everytime I start the project?

Also, I did save my project to GIT! I feel like doing the same thing again each day kills more time and I would lost the track of work! Please someone help me! Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can activate your already existing virtual environment by using following command in `ubuntu/linux`

```
source <path to your virtual env>/bin/activate
```

This activates your previous virtual environment!

Comment: so,everytime I need to activate the environment and proceed with the project?

Comment: Yes that would help you to not to create new virtual environment each time